Difference when loading style from index.html vs from index.tsx in React
The project was created using Create React App, and I have two stylesheet files (index.css and content-styles.css). There are cases where we need to customize third party component styles globally, and I did that in index.css. However, I noticed that it has become quite large, approximately 1000 lines. When considering performance, should we include index.css and other styles from public/index.html, or is it fine to include them from index.tsx?
